# What text processing tool is recommended for parsing screenplays?

Tags: text, nlp, semantic-markup, searchable

I have some plain-text kinda-structured screenplays, formatted like the example at the end of this post. I would like to parse each into some format where:

- It will be easy to pull up just stage directions that deal with a specific place.
- It will be easy to pull up just dialogue belonging to a particular character.

The most obvious approach I can think of is using `sed` or `perl` or `php` to put div tags around each block, with classes representing character, location, and whether it's stage directions or dialogue. Then, open it up as a web-page and use jQuery to pull out whatever I'm interested in. But this sounds like a roundabout way to do it and maybe it only seems like a good idea because these are tools I'm accustomed to. But I'm sure this is a recurring problem that's been solved before, so can anybody recommend a more efficient workflow that can be used on a Linux box? Thanks.

Here is some sample input:

```
      SOMEWHERE CORPORATION - OPTIONAL COMMENT
      A guy named BOB is sitting at his computer.

                             BOB
                Mmmm. Stackoverflow. I like.

      Footsteps are heard approaching.

                             ALICE
                Where's that report you said you'd have for me?

      Closeup of clock ticking.

                             BOB (looking up)
                Huh? What?

                             ALICE
                Some more dialogue.

      Some more stage directions.
```

Here is what sample output might look like:

```
      <div class='scene somewhere_corporation'>
       <div class='comment'>OPTIONAL COMMENT</div>
       <div class='direction'>A guy named BOB is sitting at his computer.</div>
       <div class='dialogue bob'>Mmmm. Stackoverflow. I like.</div>
       <div class='direction'>Footsteps are heard approaching.</div>
       <div class='dialogue alice'>Where's that report you said you'd have for me?</div>
       <div class='direction'>Closeup of clock ticking.</div>
       <div class='comment bob'>looking up</div>
       <div class='dialogue bob'>Huh? What?</div>
       <div class='dialogue alice'>Some more dialogue.</div>
       <div class='direction'>Some more stage directions.</div>
      </div>
```

I'm using DOM as an example, but again, only because that's something I understand. I'm open to whatever is considered a best practice for this type of text-processing task if, as I suspect, roll-your-own regexps and jQuery is not the best practice. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in realtime on a website? The only reason you'd use jQuery is if you were having someone input a screenplay into a text box and getting instant stage direction output.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: If I understand OP correctly, the reason (s)he suggests jQuery is that it's a good tool for extracting the content of (X)HTML nodes based on class or id info.  If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail ;)

Comment: The screenplays are text files I download, this does not need to happen in realtime or online. @dodgethesteamroller is right, it's a hammer-nail antipattern and I'm trying to avoid it by asking here for better ideas.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem.  Regexps and jQuery are indeed roundabout, but I think you have a good idea in general—to turn the semi-structured input into XML with different tags to indicate the semantics of the screenplay (direction, dialogue, comments, etc.).  You've probably already looked at other SO questions about natural language processing and seen that the libraries out there are geared more towards splitting up natural-language text into parts of speech word-by-word, which is not really what you need.  I'm leaning towards Python and `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Celtx](https://www.celtx.com/) to [import plain text scripts](http://wiki.celtx.com/index.php?title=Import_Script) and export them to HTML (and RDF/XML for the metadata) (see this [related thread](http://forums.celtx.com/viewtopic.php?t=19276) and this [blog post, which describes the file structure](http://www.cerveras.es/2011/07/understanding-celtx-rdfxml-structure/)).

Other screenplay editors like [Trelby](http://www.trelby.org/) might offer this feature, too.

---

There is also [Fountain](http://fountain.io/), a plain text markup language for screenwriting. They offer [libraries](http://fountain.io/developers) which you *might* (I did not check if they offer something for importing and converting) use for your cause:

> Fountain is free and open-source, with libraries that make it easy to add support in your apps.

---

Even if those projects can’t be used for your cause, you could at least reuse their format for your output.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is not too noisy, i.e. if you can trust some regularities like the indentation which is larger for dialogs as opposed to comments, I would use a simple [Context Free Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). You have good implementations in all languages and you'll find lot of information on SO.

If your input varies a lot, then take the machine learning route, but you'll need to have a big number of inputs with human-validated output for training, which might be a hassle.

In any case, I would never, ever use regular expressions for problems like that.